# Microsoft Graph API to get list of All Teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the List ownedObjects to get all Teams groups owned by an user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Now I want to repeat this thing to get a list of all Teams groups regardless of the specific user. Is there any documentation for this? I haven't found any.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of Teams groups from Portal, I filtered them with **`Teams enabled: Yes`** property like below:

[image]

To get the same list of Teams groups with **Microsoft Graph API**, you can make use of below query:

```
GET /groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

When I ran below query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I got the list of Teams groups successfully like this:

[image]

From the
[List all teams groups of an organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#example-1-get-a-list-of-groups-that-contain-a-team) Graph documentation:

> To get a list of all groups in the organization that have teams, get a list of all groups, and then in code find the ones that have a `resourceProvisioningOptions` property that contains `Team".
>
> Use the API with `$filter` to return only the groups that have teams.